# Old controller not connecting

Tags: ps3

My brother gave me one of his `PS3` controllers because he never uses it and I now can't get it to connect to my `PS3`. I've tried to charge it and also tried resetting it but nothing works.

What should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Did you try to connect the controller and PS3 with a mini USB cable?

To make sure the controller still works as intended, did it work for your brother's device? If not, then the controller is likely to be faulty.

Comment: I can't recall what I was trying to do, but I can confirm you need to connect the controller directly to the PlayStation, to synch up.

Comment: Yea it worked on my brother ps3 the light blinks like normal it just won't sync to the station I'm gonna let it charge over night and see if that helps and yes I do have it connected straight to the station

Comment: as @Timelord64 says the PS3 controllers must have been connected at least 1 time to the PS3 over USB to get it then work wireless

Comment: Have you tried all USB slots?

Comment: Have you tried this https://support.powera.com/hc/en-us/articles/201305844-How-do-I-sync-my-wireless-controller-for-PS3-

Comment: Yes I've tried all and I don't have the original cord that came with the station